# iOS SLComposeViewController Facebook Caption / Meta data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

Im trying to add caption/meta data from the link that is attached from the the NSURL.
I followed this article: http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/
There are a picture attached to the article at the bottom, that includes the meta data from its link. ( Windows Phone 8 tutorials... etc).

When sharing links on Facebook web, it will automatically give you this meta data so my question is how can i achieve this from iOS?

```
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
    [controller setInitialText:@"google.se"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.se"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
```

EDIT #1: I see that the Digg app do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook SDK it is not possible now using SLComposeViewController